# Why is every angreal, ter'angreal, and sa'angreal unique?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

It just seems odd to me that every *angreal*, *ter'angreal*, and *sa'angreal* has been completely unique. The only time duplicate *ter'angeals* are seen is when Egwene is mass-producing copies of Mat's weave-absorbing amulet, all of which are far less effective than the original.

Is there any mention of why this is, either from the author or from the books themselves? Perhaps back in the Age of Legends, creating duplicate *angreals* was considered 'uncool', or perhaps creating duplicate *angreals* resulted in less effectiveness, such as with the previously mentioned amulets?

Comment: In the Age of Legends, ter'angreal were the One Power equivalent of technology.  Tools and machines powered by the One Power.  They were common and mass produced.  I'm basing this on the few scenes portrayed, but it seems to me that's how Mr. Jordan was presenting them.  Most were collected and hidden or destroyed in the War of Power and the Breaking, and the processes used to create them were lost.  So they went from ubiquity to rarity by the time of Rand and co.

Comment: Still, ter'angreals like wells (for an example) seem like the should have been far more common, as weaker channellers can use them to briefly match their stronger fellows, something which would have been invaluable in brief skirmishes with the enemy.

Comment: it is surprising that wells still exist at all, since they don't increase strength, were always rare, and basically usable only in combat conditions (being shielded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely true.

**Ter'angreals**: not unique

Ter'angreals are used for many purposes, if we group them by their spesific functions we can say they don't have to be unique.

It's also can be said that there could be different shaped but same functional ter'angreals too.

We have some examples which are not unique neither by shape nor their function:

- [A'dams](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/A%27dam)
- [Bloodknife ring](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodknife_ring)

An example of different shape but same function is the a'dam Elayne produces which have no leash between the collar and the bracelet unlike the a'dams produced by Seanchans.

**Angreals** and **Sa'angreals**: may be or not unique:

As we know that to create an angreal or a sa'angreal is a long and tiring process. ([Creatin an angreal](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Angreal#Creating_an_angreal)). Their production is not mass but one by one. They have one same function, to draw more of the One Power to those who channel thruogh it.

We can say they are not unique by their function because all have only one and the same function despite the amount of One Power they allow differs. Because their production is not a mass production, we don't expect that the amount they allow should be the same but we can't say it's not possible to make two angreals which have the same limit on the amount.

What about shape? There is no evidence as we know that some angreals or sa'angreals are shaped the same but there is also no counter evidence saying it's impossible.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying. I can understand the uniqueness for angreals/sa'angreals (If you're going to spend years making something, might as well make it look cool). I also decided to look on the WoT wiki, and found that there are at least half a dozen non-unique ter'angreals, and likely more not mentioned. Guess not reading the series for so long made my memory foggy :P

Comment: @Thermophile it's easy to forget things, because there are tens of thousands of pages in the saga that contains lots of details :)

Comment: She also makes quite a few (worse) copies of the silver foxhead medallion when she borrows it from Mat.

Answer (score 2):

I must point out that the collars worn by the channeler slaves are all ter'angreal as well as a few other objects we hear about that are identical (the amulet copies being less powerful could be explained by either one she is doing it wrong or two the original is a product of non humans)

However as to your question it is never addressed in the books however the simplest answer is the more powerful artifacts were never mass produced so each would be somewhat unique the weaker ones could be the only one that survived the years or there could be crates of them in the white towers storerooms awaiting classification.  Testing grael object can be dangerous since form does not follow function you could have a crate of identical rings where half of them light up when you channel into them the other half blow up.

Comment: I did not remember the Seanchan collars, and I now remember a couple others, such as the assasin rings that were introduced towards the end of the series. The question still stands to an extent, however. Why havent energy storage ter'angreals become common so that weaker channelers could match their stronger fellows in times of need? Why weren't 'weapon' ter'angreals mass-produced in the time leading up to the Breaking of the World? I can understand why many of them are unique, but many seem like they would be more useful when made in large numbers.

Comment: @Therm the first part of that is a separate question answered by the Aes Sedai only recently rediscovered how to make grael's the second part I addressed objects could have been mass produced but over the years they got lost until only a few or even just one remain (I thought I had something about the passage of time in my answer but I must have changed my mind before I posted it)